# How to set cellForRowAtIndexPath method for 2 tableview in a storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a storyboard with 2 tableview inside. So how to set CellforrowatIndexpath, numberofrowinsection, numberofsectioninarow method for 2 tableview in storyboard.This is my code for 1 table in a storyboard. Thanks for help.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      return [moviesArray count];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"New video", @"mySectionName");
            break;
            default:
            sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }
    return sectionName;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

    }
    cell.text1Label.text=[moviesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text2Label.text=[moviesArraytext2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
```

Comment: Correctly capitalizing the method names would make the question more readable and also encourage people to take the time to read and answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up tag property for your table views in storyboard to lets say 1 and for the other table view to 2 and you have to check in the methods which table view is the data source asking about:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) { //table view one
      return [moviesArray count];
    }
    else {....} // other table view
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) { //table view one
      return 1;;
    }
    else {....} // other table view 
}
```

You have to do the same for titleForHeaderInSection:, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and other data source/delegate methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == tblCity)
    {
        return appdelegate.city.count;
    }
    else if(tableView == tblStatelist)
    {
        return appdelegate.state.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == tblCity)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=[appdelegate.city objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else if(tableView == tblStatelist)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=[appdelegate.state objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == tblCity)
    {
        txtcity.text=[appdelegate.city objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [viewCity setHidden:YES];
        appdelegate.selectedcity = txtcity.text;
    }
    else if(tableView == tblStatelist)
    {
        txtSelectedState.text=[appdelegate.state objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [stateVIew setHidden:YES];
        appdelegate.selectedstate = txtSelectedState.text;
        [self webserviceforcity];

    }
}
```